# Automatically setting the id HTML attribute of a form element in flask-wtforms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Is there a way to automatically have the `id` of a form input element itself to the name of the form *and* the name of the field variable? i.e. for a `bar` field in a `FooForm` instance, the `id` would be `foo-form--bar`.

I am currently using this approach to achieve this, but it's a bit cumbersome:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import wtforms as wtf

class FooForm(FlaskForm):
    FORM_NAME = 'foo-form'
    bar =  wtf.StringField('Bar', render_kw={'id': f'{FORM_NAME}--bar'})
```

Comment: You could probably subclass FlaskForm and/or StringField and do it there.

Comment: @KenKinder Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a go :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think subclassing complicates this, since the subclass contains only one or two lines. You can do the following:

```
def class_id(s):
    """Convert input string from PascalCase to kebab-case"""
    import re
    return re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '-', s).lower() + '-'

class MyClass(object):
    form_name = class_id(__qualname__)
    print(f"{form_name}attribute")

class OtherClass(object):
    form_name = class_id(__qualname__)
    print(f"{form_name}attribute")

>>> MyClass()
>>> OtherClass()
my-class-attribute
other-class-attribute
```

edit: sorry completely missed the part about the `id` being automatic, then subclassing would be necessary, a simple approach would be:

```
def AdjStringField(form_name, **kwargs):
    name = kwargs.get('name', 'Bar')
    return wtf.StringField(name, render_kw={
        'id': f'{}{}'.format(form_name, name.lower(),
        **kwargs.get('render_kw', {})})

class FooForm(FlaskForm):
    form_name = class_id(__qualname__)
    bar = AdjStringField(form_name)
    pipe = AdjStringField(form_name, name='Pipe', render_kw={'foo': 'bar'})
```

You can overload this for any input field type provided you supplied it as in argument object:

```
def AdjField(Field, form_name, **kwargs):
    name = kwargs.get('name', 'Bar')
    return Field(name, render_kw={
        'id': f'{}{}'.format(form_name, name.lower(),
        **kwargs.get('render_kw', {})})

>>> AdjField(wtf.StringField, 'form-name')
>>> AdjField(wtf.InputBox, 'other-name', name='Pipe', render_kw={'foo': 'bar'})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestsions Wonder if you can do this overloading some method in a `FlaskForm`  subclass as we don't want to every field type? We'd also want to check that `render_kw` hasn't been completely overridden ...

Comment: edited so that your own `render_kw` will be included and dominate in the case of overlapping 'id' key